# Not able to get class loaded to PHP script

Tags: php

I needed HTML parser for PHP and using following library - https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser

I am not able to run even a simple code. Looks like something wrong is there in way I am adding files. Below is my code.

```
<?php
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$url = 'http://google.com/';

// echo class_exists('Dom')?'yes':'no';

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadFromUrl($url);
$html = $dom->outerHtml;

echo $html;
?>
```

`echo $html` didn't gave me any output. So, I checked if `class_exists` or not, and result was `no`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Is your class included?

Comment: `use` does not magically include files. Have a look at [`require`](https://php.net/manual/function.require.php) or [*autoloading*](https://php.net/manual/function.autoload.php).

Comment: @unixarmy I don't know. I used following code - https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser#loading-url

Comment: How did you install `php-html-parser`?

Comment: @fschmengler I downloaded zip from Github

Answer (score 1):

First, `class_exists` only works with the *fully qualified class name* (i.e. including namespace):

```
class_exists('PHPHtmlParser\Dom')
```

Second, you need to include an autoloader<sup>1</sup> that tells PHP where to look for class files.

**If you installed the PHPHtmlParser with composer**, you can use the one generated by composer<sup>2</sup>:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

**If you downloaded the PHPHtmlParser source**, you have to build your own autoloader or use a third party PSR-0<sup>3</sup> compatible autoloader (because this is the standard that the library uses).

#### Simple example:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className)
    {
        $baseDir = 'PHPHtmlParser/src';
        $fileName = $baseDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
        if (stream_resolve_include_path($fileName)) {
            include $fileName;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

(adjust `'PHPHtmlParser/src/` according to where you extracted the files)

---

<sup>1) http://php.net/autoload</sup>
<sup>2) https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading</sup>
<sup>3) http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/</sup>

Comment: I didn't understand this part - `require_once 'vendor/composer/autoload.php';`

Comment: This includes the file `vendor/autoload.php` (not `vendor/composer/autoload.php`, see updated answer). It is generated by composer during `composer install` and registers an autoloader that takes care of loading classes from the right files.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using composer you **must** include `vendor/autoload.php` like this

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$url = 'http://google.com/';

// echo class_exists('Dom')?'yes':'no';

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadFromUrl($url);
$html = $dom->outerHtml;

echo $html;
?>
```

1) Download composer from https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

2) Create a file composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "paquettg/php-html-parser": "0.1.0"
    }
}
```

3) Run from your terminal `php composer.phar install` to install dependencies

4) Now edit your script and add `require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`

5) Learn to use composer properly https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: following file `require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';` is not available in zip that I downloaded from GitHub

Comment: That's not the intended way to use a composer managed library. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look inside the code of the Dom class and the `loadFromUrl` method uses the PHP core method `file_get_contents` to fetch the website's content. This method requires that the `php.ini` option `allow_url_fopen` is set to true.

If that is the case the issue could lie in class loading problems.